# How to programmatically read incoming Chromium web push notifications?

Tags: push-notification, chromium, web-push

I'm trying to figure out how I can intercept and process all web push notifications my chromium browser receives. I'd prefer to do this using Puppeteer or other similar libraries. Or I could do it using just bash commands on OS (ubuntu/debian) level, if this would be easier.

Comment: yes, but tbh I don't remember exact solution. It certainly possible.